# Re-use mapping code for immutable data class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, immutability

Updated: added some clarifications from the comments

I would like to use the same 'mapping' code for the primary constructor and `copy()` method of an immutable `data class`. How can I do this without creating an empty object first, and then using `copy()` on it?

The issue with how it is now is that if I add a new attribute with default value to `Employee` and `EmployeeForm` it would be easy to only add it in one of the two mapping functions and forget about the other (`toEmployeeNotReusable` / `copyEmployee`).

These are the data classes I'd like to map between:

```
@Entity
data class Employee(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val jobType: Int,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private val _absences: MutableSet<Absence> = mutableSetOf(),

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0 // prevents @Joffrey's answer from working
) {
    init {
        _absences.forEach { it.employee = this }
    }

    val absences get() = _absences.toSet()

    fun addAbsence(newAbsence: Absence) {
        newAbsence.employee = this
        _absences += newAbsence
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "absence")
    data class Absence(
        // ... omitted fields
    ) {
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
        lateinit var employee: Employee
    }
}


data class EmployeeForm(
    var firstName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = "",
    var jobType: Int = 0
) {
    // not reusable
    fun toEmployeeNotReusable(): Employee {
        return Employee(firstName, lastName, jobType)
    }

    // works but hacky
    fun toEmployee(): Employee {
        return copyEmployee(Employee("", "", 0))
    }

    fun copyEmployee(employee: Employee): Employee {
        return employee.copy(
            firstName = firstName,
            lastName = lastName,
            jobType = jobType
        )
    }
}
```

While mutability would be fine, in my case, I'd be interested to know how this would be possible.

Comment: What do you mean by reusable? How would you like it to be reused? Can you show an example? I don't see right now what your problem is with `toEmployeeNotReusable()`.

Comment: @Joffrey the issue is that I have to specify every attribute twice, so at some point in the future I will forget to add a new attribute in one of the two functions

Comment: What exactly is the goal? Why isn't the method `toEmployee` defined as `fun toEmployee() = Employee(firstName, lastName, jobType)`? I think answering this question would help me understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Fred because if code changes, new attributes will be forgotten to add to one of the two functions (`copyEmployee` / `toEmployee`)

Comment: @Shyro Your `Employee` constructor only has mandatory fields, without default values. If something is changed, it will be detected at compile time in the `toEmployeeNotReusable()` method, so you will have to update the form accordingly. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: not true in my opinion. If you add more attributes to `Employee` you'll have 2 options. Either make it optional by giving it a default value. In the case you make it optional, then you do have to look for instances of it's creation, but in the case you don't make it optional, then wherever you construct an `Employee` object you need to pass the value for the attribute or the code won't build. Also, I don't understand why reusable code means that you won't have to change it if you add more things to your data classes.

Comment: @Fred same here, I think he just misused the word "reusable", OP probably meant resilient or robust, or something along these lines.

Comment: @Shyro Your edit is incorrect. If you add an attribute, you don't need to change your `copy()` call, because copy doesn't require all attributes to be passed in, that's the whole point of it. Unless you meant you added an attribute to the form class as well?

Comment: Yes if i added it to the form class as well. The issue really  only occurs with new attributes that have a default value as you've said. Mandatory ones will give a compiler error which is fine, but with optional ones it'd be easy to add it in one function and miss it in the other. That's why i'd want to re-use some code between the two. And yeah sorry about my unclear wording. (Also I realized i left out some context when trying to create a minimal repro, will add back later)

Comment: @Shyro ok I think I see what you mean, now

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid listing the attributes 4 times would be to declare `Employee` as an interface instead, and use the "mutable" version, the form, as the only data class implementing it. You would have the "read-only" view using the interface, but you would technically only use the mutable instance behind the scenes.

This would follow what Kotlin designers have done for `List` vs `MutableList`.

```
interface Employee {
    val firstName: String
    val lastName: String
    val jobType: Int
}

data class EmployeeForm(
    override var firstName: String = "",
    override var lastName: String = "",
    override var jobType: Int = 0
): Employee {

    fun toEmployee(): Employee = this.copy()

    fun copyEmployee(employee: Employee): Employee = this.copy(
            firstName = firstName,
            lastName = lastName,
            jobType = jobType
    )
}
```

However, this implies that the form has all fields of an employee, which you probably don't want.

Also, I would personally prefer what you had done in the beginning, listing twice the field would not be a problem, just write tests for your functions, and when you want to add functionality, you'll add tests for that functionality anyway.

Comment: Interesting idea, but as you mentioned it doesn't work if the form doesn't have the same fields (I edited the question accordingly with more a accurate representation of my situation). 

Listing it twice would also be my go-to way if there's no other solution. I was just hoping there would be a clear, straight forward way to do this.Unfortunately this also means that both functions need to be tested instead of just one ;)

Comment: I think you forgot to use `employee` in `copyEmployee(employee: Employee)`. The method is effectively doing the same as just `toEmployee()`. I'm still not sure what the OP meant, but I suppose we want a "copy" method from employee to employee form and vice versa, that gets auto-updated everytime we add fields in one of the classes?

Comment: @Fred I think the OP wants to use the given employee as base and override only the fields that the form supports. But with my solution, the form must implement all employees fields and thus it makes no sense to have the `copyEmployee()` method in the first place, because we would override all the fields of the given `employee`. In fact, in the end, this solution is useless I must admit.

Comment: Anyway, I don't like the fact that the `EmployeeForm` implements `Employee` anyway, because a form is not an employee. I wrote this solution for the sake of the exercise only, but I would turn away from it anyway for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using reflection: check list of properties in `Employee` and `EmployeeForm`, call the constructor by the matching names (using [`callBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/call-by.html#kotlin.reflect.KCallable%24callBy%28kotlin.collections.Map%28%28kotlin.reflect.KParameter%2C+kotlin.Any%29%29%29) to handle default parameters). The drawback, of course, is that you won't get compile-time errors if any properties are missing (but for this case, any test would probably fail and tell you about the problem).

Approximate and untested (don't forget to add the `kotlin-reflect` dependency):

```
inline fun <reified T> copy(x: Any): T {
    val construct = T::class.primaryConstructor
    val props = x::class.memberProperties.associate { 
        // assumes all properties on x are valid params for the constructor
        Pair(construct.findParameterByName(it.name)!!,
             it.call(x))
    }
    return construct.callBy(props)
}

// in EmployeeForm
fun toEmployee() = copy<Employee>(this)
```

You can make an equivalent which *is* compile-time checked with Scala macros, but I don't think it's possible in Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks for the creative idea, but I'd rather refrain from using reflection for such a minor inconvenience. I see now that there is no straight forward, obvious way to do what I intended (which is fine) so I'll just stick to having the two methods. Thanks anyway